# make4ht: Reference site title in other HTML meta tags (e.g. "og:title")

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

I would like to add metadata (via `meta` tags and JSON-LD) to my `tex4ht` output, and for this leverage the `title` tag content in some places.

Using the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\title{Some Book}
\subtitle{A novel}
\author{Some Author}

\makeatletter
\let\mytitle\@title
\let\mysubtitle\@subtitle
\let\myauthor\@author
\let\mydate\@date
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{A great beginning}

\end{document}
```

with the following `make4ht.cfg`:

```latex
\Preamble{xhtml,ext=html,charset="utf-8"}
\Configure{TITLE+}{\mytitle{}: \mysubtitle{} | \myauthor{}}
\Configure{chapterTITLE+}{\chaptername{} \thechapter{}: #1 | \mytitle{}: \mysubtitle{} | \myauthor{}}
\Configure{likechapterTITLE+}{#1 | \mytitle{}: \mysubtitle{} | \myauthor{}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<meta property="og:title" content="\LikeRef{TITLE+}" />}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I get exactly what I want for the `title` tag of each page, i.e. the book name (title, subtitle, author) if producing a single HTML and the chapter number and title prefixed if splitting by chapters.

Is there a way to leverage this e.g. for `og:title` or other metadata fields?
The indicated example using `\LikeRef{TITLE+}` does not appear to work (empty output).

For completeness, I am compiling with:

```
make4ht --format html5 --config make4ht.cfg --utf8 book.tex  "2,sec-filename,sections+"
```

but I'd also like the "single page version" to work:

```
make4ht --format html5 --config make4ht.cfg --utf8 book.tex  "1,sec-filename,sections+"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,ext=html,charset="utf-8"}
\Tag{mytitle}{\mytitle: \mysubtitle\space| \myauthor}
\Configure{TITLE+}{\LikeRef{mytitle}}
\Configure{chapterTITLE+}{\chaptername{} \thechapter{}: #1 | \mytitle{}: \mysubtitle{} | \myauthor{}}
\Configure{likechapterTITLE+}{#1 | \mytitle{}: \mysubtitle{} | \myauthor{}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\Hnewline<meta property="og:title" content="\LikeRef{mytitle}" />}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The important change is that we save the custom title to the `\Tag{mytitle}` property, which can be then read with the `\LikeRef{mytitle}` command. `\LikeRef{TITLE+}` doesn't work because `\Configure{TITLE+}` doesn't save the property using the `\Tag` command, so it isn't available in `\LikeRef`. But this property is saved by `\maketitle`, with `\@title` as value, which is the reason why I chose a different name.

This is the result:

```html
<head><title>Chapter 1: Introduction — Some Book: A novel — Some Author</title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='sample.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='sample.tex' name='src' /> 
 
<meta content='Some Book: A novel | Some Author' property='og:title' /></head>
```

Edit:

If you want to have the same title and `og:title`, you can use a DOM filter. Try this file, `build.lua`:

```lua
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"

local process = domfilter {
  function(dom)
    -- copy current page title from <title> to <meta property="og:title">
    local head = dom:query_selector("head")[1]
    -- find head element for faster processing
    if head then
      local title
      for _, el in ipairs(head:query_selector("title")) do
        title = el:get_text()
      end
      if title then
        for _, meta in ipairs(head:query_selector("meta[property='og:title']")) do
          meta:set_attribute("content", title)
        end
      end
    end
    return dom
  end
}

Make:match("html$", process)
```

Compile using:

```
make4ht --format html5 --config make4ht.cfg -e build.lua --utf8 book.tex  "2,sec-filename,sections+"
```

This is the result:

```html
<head><title>Chapter 1: Introduction — Some Book: A novel — Some Author</title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='sample.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='sample.tex' name='src' /> 
 
<meta content='Chapter 1: Introduction — Some Book: A novel — Some Author' property='og:title' /></head>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's almost there — my question was not clear enough, I think. I was aiming to get exactly the content of the `title` tag in the property, i.e. when not splitting by sections, with the new config file, I get the correct result. But when splitting by sections (chapters), I'd like the title to be `Chapter 1: Introduction — Some Book: A novel — Some Author`, i.e. including the chapter title and number. Is that possible, too?

Comment: @OliverFreyermuth ah, this seems to be more difficult. You can use DOM filters for this. See my edit.

Comment: Wow, this works great, as usual! It works perfectly well. Thanks for the comments in the Lua code, too, this really helps — I am also considering using this approach to generate the JSON-LD now (preferred by some search engines for rich metadata), Lua seems to be well-suited for that.

Comment: @OliverFreyermuth sure, you can add a lot of custom elements with Lua filters. see the LuaXML documentation for details about the DOM object, it has lot of useful functions